# Convert Int8Array to byte[] javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dwr, typed-arrays

I am trying to pass an Int8Array, which is created from an array buffer to a java method via DWR, which accepts it as a byte[] parameter.

Javascript :

```
   uploadFiles: function(eve) {
        var fileContent = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < this.filesToBeUploaded.length; i++){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(fileToBeUploaded) {
                return function(e) {
                    file = e.target.result;
                    var view = new Int8Array(file);
                    // fileContent object contains the content of the read file
                };
            })(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.filesToBeUploaded[i]);
        }            
    }
```

I want the contents of view to be passed to this method -

```
public boolean uploadFile(String fileName, byte[] fileContent) {}
```

DWR seems to be unable to marshal the **view** object to the java layer. Is there any setting I am missing?

Comment: The ArrayBuffer (file) is the actual byte-buffer (Uint8Array is just a view on top of it). Have you tried just passing that directly?