# How to edit a byte at a given index in a "ArrayBuffer"

Tags: javascript

I can not found a way to change a value in an ArrayBuffer.

I am able to print the content of an `ArrayBuffer` by using a `TextDecoder`. When printing the buffer there is a string. I want to change one char on the string by editing one byte on the buffer. I was able to access one byte on the buffer by converting it to an Int8Array but I am not sure on how to converting it again to an `ArrayBuffer` after editing the byte

```
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
console.log('ArrayBuffer string content : ', enc.decode(data));
let view = new Int8Array(data);
view[56] = 48;
view[57] = 48;
// Convert view again to an ArrayBuffer
//console.log('ArrayBuffer string new content : ', enc.decode(data));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861112/438992, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer-String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set method on your Int8Array directly :

```
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
console.log('ArrayBuffer string content : ', enc.decode(data));
let view = new Int8Array(data);
view.set([48], 56);
view.set([48], 57);
```

Comment: But this will not chnange the byte value in the data variable

Comment: What type is your data variable ? Could you show the code where data is initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the top answer:

```
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
console.log('ArrayBuffer string content : ', enc.decode(data));
let view = new Int8Array(data);
view.set([48], 56);
view.set([48], 57);
```

It actually does change the byte value in the data variable.
I spend the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to do this, myself.
Then I finally understood that when you create the new Int8Array(), you're not creating a copy of the data - you're just creating a different type of pointer to it.
It's messy, it's confusing, but it works.
Cheers!